# Получить подстроку до символа регуляркой

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Входные данные:

> link/?param=value 
>   link/ 
>   link/section/

Выходные:

> link

Как регуляркой получить все, что до слеша (выражение замены)? 
Добавил третий вариант во входных данных. 
Пытаюсь получить так: (.+?/) 
В третьем случае выдаёт: link/section/

Comment: зависит от того в качестве чего получить. если в качестве группы захвата подходит, то `(.*?)/`, если полного совпадения, то `.*?(?=\/)`

Comment: @Mike в первом случае слэш забыли заэкранировать.

Comment: можно так `([^\/]+)`

Comment: тестирую: /test/link/section/ Рег: ^/test/([^\/]+)/ Получаю: linksection/